# how to disable back button in android

Tags: android, back-button

i am making swap application... i want to disable back button. so i use this code... and passed intent in to it..

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
        // do something on back.
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

but while running when i press back button on emulator it updates activity but when i repress back button it switch to the home page of an emulator.. please suggest is their any other method

Comment: You can override either of these method `dispatchKeyEvent`, `onBackPressed`, `onKeyDown`. Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44714357/6521116) for more.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // do nothing.
}
```

Comment: i just applied @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // do nothing.
    return; }   
and by applying intent now i can switch to the page where i want

Comment: Has this really been up for more than two years with "do not return true" from a `void` method? Come on...there are several more complete and correct answers here.

Answer (score 16):

```
 @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {

    //super.onBackPressed();
    if(SOME_CONDITION_TO_CHECK){
        //THIS BLOCK WILL NOT DO ANYTHING AND WOULD DISABLE BACK BUTTON             
    }else{
       super.onBackPressed();
       //THIS BLOCK WILL BE CALLED IF ABOVE COND IS FALSE, AND WOULD ENABLE BACK BUTTON
    }   

 }
```

Answer (score 6):

Did you try onBackPressed() ?

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
       // Do as you please
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is my solution 
it works using Android 2.2

override onBackPressed() ...

```
public void onBackPressed() {
   // check if you are in the right mode 
   if (getCurrentState() == FORM_STATE_BROWSE ) {
       // ok do default back action
       super.onBackPressed();
   }

   // exit skipping "onBackPressed()"
   return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You **must** add return in order for this to successfully work on all devices, my Note-3 & HTC still go back if I don't include return!

```
  @Override
  public void onBackPressed() {
        return;
  }
```

Comment: That seems very strange because Java can see no difference between no return and return in this case. Return just exits the method doing nothing.

Comment: Just posting what happened, I don't have a technical reason.

Answer (score 0):

Like if you want to move on some activity by pressing back button,override this method in your activity

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // do nothing.
        Intent intent = new Intent(SocialPlugIns.this, MainActivity.class);
        Log.i("Hello", "This is Coomon Log");
        startActivity(intent);
           return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to override `onBackPressed()` function. Below I am giving a way:

```
   @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
       //make some alert for the user
    }
```