# How to catch event with hardware back button on android?

Tags: android

How to catch event with hardware back button on android ? I need to supress user to go back and I when click on back button on phone to show message and not to go on previous activity. How to do that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable back button in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779954/disable-back-button-in-android)

Answer (score 71):

you can do by this

1. override the onBackPressed() method into your Activity like this way

   ```
   public void onBackPressed(){
        // do something here and don't write super.onBackPressed()
   }
   ```
2. override the onKeyDown() method

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
       switch(keyCode){
       case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
           // do something here 
           return true;
       }
       return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
   }
   ```

Comment: Is it really necessary to override `onKeyDown()` too? When the back key is pressed, won't `onBackPressed()` be called?

Comment: @LarsH in case you are still wondering: No. The first solution is for API Level 5 (Android 2.0) and above. The second solution is for API Level < 5. Referring to [this comment/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312334/how-to-handle-back-button-in-activity#comment5992484_5312391)

Answer (score 10):

Override the method `onBackPressed()` in whatever `Activity` you want to create a different behaviour to the back button.

These question are equal to yours (and could have been found by a simple search):

[how to disable back button in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673358/how-to-disable-back-button-in-android)

[Disable back button in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779954/disable-back-button-in-android)

Answer (score 2):

You can suppress user "back" action with `onKeyDown()` in your activity like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK))
    {
        //do actions like show message
        return false;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```