# onKey method never execute

Tags: android

I implemented an override to the back button key in the device. now for some reason the method onKey never execute and there fore when i click on the back button the application is minimize to the back instead doing the onKey code.
i am not sure what is the problem so i will upload my all code.

This is my code:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        getView().requestFocus();
        getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                        String frag_name = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() - 1).getName();
                        Log.d("frag name is", frag_name);
                        Fragment fragment = null;
                        switch (frag_name){
                            case "back_to_attending":
                                fragment = new AttendingListFragmentController();
                                break;
                            case "back_to_invitations":
                                fragment = new InvitationsFragmentController();
                                break;
                            case "waiting_list":
                                fragment = new WaitingEventListFragmentController();
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }

                        if(fragment != null){
                            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                            fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate();
                            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment,frag_name).addToBackStack(frag_name).commit();
                        }

                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Please post only the relevant part. Nobody is going to read a whole file.

Comment: yes but if  i will provide onlt the onKey code how you can know that other part of the code will not be relevant?

Comment: look at my updated code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to catch event with hardware back button on android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8094715/how-to-catch-event-with-hardware-back-button-on-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public class MyClass implements OnKeyListener {
...
```

Then override the method `onKey`

```
@Override
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    //do what you want
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Try to set the focus on the main layout of your activity.

Comment: how can i do that? i have 2 layouts in this fragment maybe because of that its happend

Comment: Watch here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150656/how-to-set-focus-on-a-view-when-a-layout-is-created-and-displayed

Answer (score 0):

What results do you get when you override onBackPressed() ?

Comment: @Nicolas Cortell i think his code currently is similar to what you have suggested.

Comment: i am using in all the rest of my fragments/ activities the onKey method and its working so i dont think is matter which method is it. maybe there is other problem in the rest of the code but i cant find it.

Comment: @KunalKhaire if he's using a `Fragment` your code won't work

Comment: so what should i use? because in my other fragments there is implementation of onKey method and its working