# Disable back button

Tags: android

I am working in an android application and I want to disable a back button in my android application. I am redirecting it to a url and I want to disable back button there. Please help me.

Here is ma code

```
public class PrepareRequestTokenActivity extends Activity {

    final String TAG = getClass().getName();

    private OAuthConsumer consumer;
    private OAuthProvider provider;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        try {
            setContentView(R.layout.twitter);
            ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(PrepareRequestTokenActivity.this, "", 
                    "Loading. Please wait...", true);
            this.consumer = new CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer(
                    Constants.CONSUMER_KEY, Constants.CONSUMER_SECRET);
            this.provider = new CommonsHttpOAuthProvider(Constants.REQUEST_URL,
                    Constants.ACCESS_URL, Constants.AUTHORIZE_URL);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error creating consumer / provider", e);
        }

        Log.i(TAG, "Starting task to retrieve request token.");
        new OAuthRequestTokenTask(this, consumer, provider).execute();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
            Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "back button pressed");
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }


    /**
     * Called when the OAuthRequestTokenTask finishes (user has authorized the
     * request token). The callback URL will be intercepted here.
     */
    @Override
    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        final Uri uri = intent.getData();
        if (uri != null
                && uri.getScheme().equals(Constants.OAUTH_CALLBACK_SCHEME)) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Callback received : " + uri);
            Log.i(TAG, "Retrieving Access Token");
            new RetrieveAccessTokenTask(this, consumer, provider, prefs)
                    .execute(uri);


            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);

            finish();
        }
    }




    public class RetrieveAccessTokenTask extends AsyncTask<Uri, Void, Void> {

        private Context context;
        private OAuthProvider provider;
        private OAuthConsumer consumer;
        private SharedPreferences prefs;

        public RetrieveAccessTokenTask(Context context, OAuthConsumer consumer,
                OAuthProvider provider, SharedPreferences prefs) {
            this.context = context;
            this.consumer = consumer;
            this.provider = provider;
            this.prefs = prefs;
        }

        /**
         * Retrieve the oauth_verifier, and store the oauth and
         * oauth_token_secret for future API calls.
         */
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Uri... params) {
            final Uri uri = params[0];
            final String oauth_verifier = uri
                    .getQueryParameter(OAuth.OAUTH_VERIFIER);

            try {
                provider.retrieveAccessToken(consumer, oauth_verifier);

                final Editor edit = prefs.edit();
                edit.putString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN, consumer.getToken());
                edit.putString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET,
                        consumer.getTokenSecret());
                edit.commit();

                String token = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN, "");
                String secret = prefs.getString(OAuth.OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET, "");

                consumer.setTokenWithSecret(token, secret);                             

                Log.i(TAG, "OAuth - Access Token Retrieved");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "OAuth - Access Token Retrieval Error", e);
            }

            return null;
        }

    }
```

Comment: See [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5673358/how-to-disable-back-button-in-android][1]

Answer (score 2):

Override the onBackPressed method

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   return;
}
```

requires API Level 5 or higher

Answer (score 1):

Return true instead of super.onKeyDown(..,..)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onKeyDown%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29

Answer (score 1):

Avoid calling parent behavior, i.e, remove super.onBackPressed() in your override method

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // do nothing.
}