# Android:How to disable back press of handset?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disable back button in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779954/disable-back-button-in-android)

i don't want to dismiss my dialog through back button, is there any way to disable back press of handset? when i press back button my dialog got cancelled , but after that cancellation i need to pass one message but how i know where flow of activity goes after cancellation of dialog?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normal back button with unchanged behaviour, add that to your activity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

To disable the back button:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // do nothing
}
```

Comment: dialog is showing and when i pass this code of disable , and i press back , dialog gets cancelled

Answer (score 1):

You can set your dialog as non-cancelable (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html, `setCancelable(false);`) and you can also override `onBackPressed()` in your activity.

Although, I couldn't tell from your question what do you want to do exactly. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

`Dialog.setCancellable(false)` should be enough. It is for me.