# Disable backbutton click on edit text android

Tags: android, android-edittext, back-button

I am having an edit text, and while the user is entering data in it, i want the back button to be disabled. Please help if anyone has done this before.

Comment: Did you try to override onBackPressed method?

Answer (score 1):

You can override the [onBackPressed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29) method of your activity.

But please think about this twice. Normally this is nothing the user would expect.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, but i want to stop back button only when the edittext is on, rest of the time, i want the user to use the back button, inside edittext can we do this?

Comment: Also, this is not working for edittext if i place this in the main activity!

Answer (score 0):

Try using this link:
[Disable back button in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779954/disable-back-button-in-android)

```
   @Override
       public void onBackPressed() {
   }
```

Requires `API Level 5 or higher`.

This is a duplicate question and this answer seems to do what you want.