# Onclick back button the application stops

Tags: android, back-button

I have one problem regarding my app,when i click back button my application is getting  finish.i need to prevent it.How could i make it .

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   Log.d("CDA", "onBackPressed Called");
   Intent setIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

   startActivity(setIntent);
}
```

I have tried something like this.But its not working .Actually what i need is when i will click back button ,the application should not finish it should run in background.can anybody help me out.@Thanks

Comment: does it finish with crash/error?

Comment: what does mean by 'should run in background'.. is there any special codes what what you want to do?

Comment: what the mean `run in background`, ? either you can disable back button or don't finish activity before you call new activity in stack

Comment: @Waqas no it is not showing error/crash, but i need that  on click back button the application should not finish ,it should always run in background

Comment: @chintankhetiya how do you disable backbutton

Comment: Use a service if you want your app to keep running in the background.

Comment: @PankajKumar run in background means the activity should not close it should keep working

Comment: @vickey how could i make it,

Comment: An activity is a single, focused thing that the user can do. You need to create a service to do the background work.

Comment: Use Services for this... can't be implemented via Activity

Comment: take a look at these:  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html and http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779954/disable-back-button-in-android @Raghunandan is it okay ? i am using this and disable as per needs

Comment: @vickey is there any FLAG that will keep the application on running in background

Comment: No there isn't. There is an Activty method moveTaskToBack(boolean nonRoot). Have a look at that. Although I strongly urge you to use a service.

Comment: @vickey how could i used that service in activity

Comment: You create a service just like an activity and bind it to your main activity. Once started, Services are designed to run in the background. Click on the following links to understand services: developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html and vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing it like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Log.d("CDA", "onBackPressed Called");
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);

    startActivity(intent);
}
```

By doing this, your activity will not be destroyed (i.e. `onDestroy` will not be raised). But also, there's no guarantee that Android will preserve your activity for long.

In case, you  are running a process that you want to keep on running even in background, then I would suggest you to go for `Service` or `IntentService`.

Comment: This is same as pressing the home button but it does not guarantee that the app will keep running seamlessly.

Comment: Thanks ,using the above code does the activity will never close

Comment: @vickey how could i supposed to make it

Comment: @vickey I think she didnt want `onDestroy` to be raised on her activity even when back-key is pressed.

Comment: @Waqas right and i need that the application also still work in minimizing

Comment: @priya2134412 then go for `Service` or `IntentService`

Comment: @Waqas Is there any FLAG intent that will perform that service

Comment: No! you need to create your own class that extends Service. Later, use threads to perform your desired task(s) in that service

Comment: @Waqas thanks it is working fine..shall i continue with this code or add service

Comment: In the long run, I would suggest you to make use of Service because its the way to perform background tasks

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "it should run in background"? Why would you want that? If the user wants to keep the app opened, he can use the home button and the app won't be closed, if he presses the back button he wants to close the app. If want to have something that is still running even after the user closes the application you should take a look at Service http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html, this will continue running even after the user closes the app