# disable "BACK" button in Android?

Tags: android, back

Is their a way of disable a BACK button on my mobile? because while i'll transfer it to my mobile the BACK button is activated so that it can back the previous page. Please help me to disable BACK button while my app is running.

Comment: You can override either of these method `dispatchKeyEvent`, `onBackPressed`, `onKeyDown`. Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44714357/6521116) for more.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Override the `onBackPressed()` of your activity

```
@SuppressLint("MissingSuperCall")
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{

   // super.onBackPressed(); // Comment this super call to avoid calling finish() or fragmentmanager's backstack pop operation.
}
```

You may suppress lint's error by adding `@SuppressLint("MissingSuperCall")` as per Matthew Read pointed out.

Comment: where i can put this code in my MAinActivity? or in all class?

Comment: @user3098496 in all activities where you want to disable back button.

Comment: the back button in my mobile? not in my apps?

Comment: You may also need to annotate the method: `@SuppressLint("MissingSuperCall")`

Comment: is this work on android 10

Comment: @Ahmad I believe yes. After checking Activity documentation, there's no updates/deprecation in the said method. Still the same.

Answer (score 6):

This way works for all versions of *Android*, and will work with libraries that may override the default functionality in their `Activities` (such as *cocos2d-x*):

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
    return (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK ? true : super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is very simple.. put this code in every activity of your android code if you wish to disable the back button for complete aplication

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{

   //thats it
}
```

and you are done