# Prevent the back button in the login activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an activity named MainActivity and another called LoginActivity.
The main activity cannot be visible to logged out users. In the onCreate method of MainAcitivity I verifiy if the user is logged out and then I create the LoginActivity.

The problem is that if the user press the back button of the cellphone, the app go back to the MainActivity.

How I prevent this?

The code of the LoginAcitivity creation is this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(_context, LoginActivity.class);

i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);         

i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

_context.startActivity(i);
```

Comment: check for the login in the onResume of your mainActivity, or in onActivityForResult.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call `finish();` just after `startActivity()`. This will kill MainActivity so the back button will close the app.

Comment: Thanks! Works fine like I want =D

Answer (score 3):

after:
_context.startActivity(i);

put:
finish();

Answer (score 2):

If you're fine with just disabling the back button in the LogInActivity, you can do so with the following code in the LogInActivity class:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
}
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779954/disable-back-button-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity
    android:noHistory="true"
    android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
    android:noHistory="true"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
    android:name=".activity.LoginActivity" />
```

I tried "**noHistory**" in the file "AndroidManifest.xml". Main- and LoginActivity. Works so far in my app.

- "Back-Button" terminates the app in Login- and MainActivity