# how to disable back button for particular activity

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an Android app in which first screen is **Login screen**. after successful log-in, **Home screen** appears. But the problem is when I press Back button, it goes to login screen again. I want to **disable the back button** while I am on **home screen**  and display an alert box asking

> are you sure you want to exit

I have searched many examples, but didn't find any perfect solution
I have tried using `public void onBackPressed() {}` method, but don't know what to implement. My min SDK version is 15.

Comment: you can put empty implementation in onBackPressed(){}

Comment: user after `oncreate()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable back button in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779954/disable-back-button-in-android)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your activity just override `onBackPressed()`

```
  @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
      AlertDialog diaBox = AskOption();
      diaBox.show();
    }

 private AlertDialog AskOption()
 {
    AlertDialog myQuittingDialogBox =new AlertDialog.Builder(this) 
        .setTitle("Exit") 
        .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?") 
        .setIcon(R.drawable.delete)
        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) { 
            finish();
            }   
        })
        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        })
        .create();
        return myQuittingDialogBox;

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

If your actual desire is to prevent user to go back to login activity, you can use other options as well :

1. finish() login activity after you call home activity. So you won't need to ignore back press.
2. put noHistory="true" in Android Manifest for login screen, when the user goes to home screen, they won't be able to come back with back button again.

and last

override onBackPressed() method in home activity. But as I said if you just want to prevent user to go back, you shouldn't override this method. They should be able to press back button and quit the app.

```
public void onBackPressed(){
}
```

Comment: Then please mark this answer as solved with the green check on the left.

Answer (score 2):

You need to override the onBackPressed() and remove the super.onBackPressed() line

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed(); //  remove this line
    }
```

Meantime if you do login and navigate to home screen it is a best practice that you finish the login screen and navigate to home screen. So the user wont see the login screen again..
Let me tell you a sample scenario

- Splash Screen (Finishes this activity and move to login)
- Login Screen
- If login succeds then finish login screen and navigate to home screen. So if user presses back you can ask for an alert whether you
  want to quit from app or not.
- If user launches app again it will repeat the same process.

Answer (score 1):

Just leave the `OnBackPressed()` method empty. Does it for me

Answer (score 0):

Override `onBackPressed()` and remove line `super.onBackPressed();`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

}
```

Know when you press back it won't go back.

Answer (score 0):

use `onbackpressed()`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
//super.onBackPressed();
}
```

i hope this will help you..

Answer (score 0):

Leave OnBackPressed() empty and, finish () login activity when you navigate from login to home page

Answer (score 0):

its very simple,just override the backpress and remove super calling like:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){

}
```

leave this  method blank and you will get what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
// do nothing.
}
```

Do not return true.Just check the condition.