# disable keycode button using public int

Tags: android, keycode

How to disable keycode button using `public int` instead of `public boolean`? I already search in this site such as "[Disable back button in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779954/disable-back-button-in-android)" but all of them using `public boolean` or `public void`.

Comment: But why public int? You didn't mention reason behind implementation. The methods which you are telling about boolean and void are abstract methods declared in Activity class.