# How can I disable the backward button in the activity in android

Tags: android, webview

Consider we have an activity that in that we load a `webview`. Now I want to disable the backward button in this activity whether  hardware and whether software in all the android versions.

[image]

Comment: Possibly duplicate with many other questions in SO, such as [Disable back button in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779954/disable-back-button-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are targeting below API `android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR`, please do this,

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
     if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

         return true;
     }
     return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);    
}
```

If you are targeting higher APIs, then do this in your Activity,

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // Do something here or leave it blank
}
```

If you want to perform some operation, put some code there or just leave it blank to block back button press.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to call onBackPressed and leave empty in your activity class

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
}
```