# Android "back" button stop navigating to parent activity, because user is not logged in

Tags: android, android-activity

I am new to Android. I am doing simple app with login/logout.
My launcher activity is HomePageActivity. At HomePageActivity user authorization is checked and if user is not logged in he is sent to LoginActivity. The problem is that when user clicks physical "back" button he is sent to HomePageActivity.

How can i prevent this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779954/disable-back-button-in-android
guy with your reputation should know how to use stack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to `finish()` the activity before sending to login activity, and then the back button won't be able to navigate to the HomePageActivity activity.

For example:

```
finish();
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Handle `onBackPressed();` for your activity

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        // Your code
    }
```