# How to disable back button pressed for webview in android?

Tags: android, webview

How to disable back button pressed for webview in android ?

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
{
     if (wv1 != null && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
                     && wv1.canGoBack() )
     {

        wv1.goBack();
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Please give some more information. What do you want to achieve? I did not get what you are asking.

Comment: Is the webview is always visible ??

Comment: [Disable back button in android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4779954/6521116)

Comment: You can override either of these method `dispatchKeyEvent`, `onBackPressed`, `onKeyDown`. Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44714357/6521116) for more.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to disable back button action when the `WebView` Visible and enable back button action if the `WebView` in not Visible **try the below code in your Activity**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   if(webview.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE){
      // dont pass back button action
      if(webview.canGoBack()){
         webview.goBack();
      }
      return;
   }else{
      // pass back button action
      super.onBackPressed();
   }
}
```

Comment: nice one! for me, I didn't ever want the webview to "steal" the back button press, so inside `public void onBackPressed()` I just had the one line `super.onBackPressed();`

Answer (score 2):

Simply override the onBackPressed() method.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() { }
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
   @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
      if(webview.canGoBack()){
         webview.goBack();
      }
    else{
      super.onBackPressed();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to make it,

**Solution 1, overriding dispatchKeyEvent()**

> dispatchKeyEvent()(API Level 1, Android 1.0)

Refer to my answer [use dispatchKeyEvent to disable back button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44714357/6521116)

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

---

**Solution 2, overriding onBackPressed()**

> onBackPressed() (API Level 5, Android 2.0)

Refer to [Use onBackPressed() to disable back button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4780009/6521116)

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
}
```

---

**Solution 3, overriding onKeyDown()**

> onKeyDown() (API Level 1, Android 1.0)

Refer to [Use onKeyDown() to disable back button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4779997/6521116)

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
     if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
     //preventing default implementation previous to android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.ECLAIR
     return true;
     }
     return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);    
}
```

Comment: I want the browser to not perform the default back operation after the user presses the back key. Instead, JavaScript get a key event(`document.onkeydown` and the keyCode = 8). Is this possible?

Comment: @forDream I think it's possible, you need to make sure the js event or the java event first. And you may also pass the click event between js and java code.

Comment: In general, I want to pass a keycode to webview for any value, such as keycode `-1` / `-2` or something else.
I.e. trigger `document.onkeydown / onkeypress / onkeyup`

Answer (score 0):

You have add below code in Activity for disable activity back pressed

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Add this below code in java file : 

WebView mwebView;
Button backButton1;

  backButton1 = findViewById(R.id.backButton1);
 mwebView = findViewById(R.id.mwebView);

backButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mWebView.destroy();
            }
        });
```