# How to use back button to go back with XWalkView of CrossWalk, or disable it?

Tags: android, back-button, keyevent, crosswalk, xwalkview

I use below code to go back in webview at first try. But for the low render ability, I used XWalkView replace the WebView.

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:

                if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
                    mWebView.goBack();
                } else {
                    finish();
                    if (MainActivity.mTencent.isSessionValid()) {
                        MainActivity.logout();
                    }
                }
                return true;
        }

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

When change to XWalkView, I only find [this](https://crosswalk-project.org/apis/embeddingapidocs/reference/org/xwalk/core/XWalkNavigationHistory.html) about go back in the XWalkView. But I cannot find an example about to use it.
When I not implement the back button envent, the app will exit after I double click the back button.

My question is:
1. How to use go back in the XWalkView, if some code may be more helpful.
2. How can I disable the back button click event, when I not use the go back functon.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [Disable back button in webview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44715005/6521116)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After days of digging, I solved this: put this in the activity xwalkview in. Though this works, but the go back sometimes lost some history. So I also want someone give a better answer here.

for goback:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    //WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    XWalkView mXWalkView = (XWalkView) findViewById(R.id.xWalkView);
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:

                if (mXWalkView.getNavigationHistory().canGoBack()) {
                    mXWalkView.getNavigationHistory().navigate(XWalkNavigationHistory.Direction.BACKWARD, 1) ;
                } else {
                    finish();
                    if (MainActivity.mTencent.isSessionValid()) {
                        MainActivity.logout();
                    }
                }
                return true;
        }

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

for disable back event you can override either of these method `dispatchKeyEvent`, `onBackPressed`, `onKeyDown`. Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44714357/6521116) for more.

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: This solution is much better than the one being awarded 50 bounties.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `xwalkviewhistory.cangoback()`

Comment: Yeah, I know this , but I don't know how to use it from the manual. Will you give some more info.

Comment: and how to disable it?