# How to disable physical back button for webview in android?

Tags: android

In my android application.

I am opening one web page using `webview`. So at that time I want to disable physical back button of mobile. please anybody help?

here i tried.

1. `onbackpressed()` function.

in my activity class, i have written,
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

}

but didn't work.

Comment: can you update the question with  your onbackpress()

Comment: [How to disable back button pressed for webview in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44715005/6521116)

Comment: [Disable back button in android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4779954/6521116)

Answer (score 1):

Just don't call the super class:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(allowedToClose) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want that nothing happens on pressing back button , just leave the onBackPressed function empty.

Remember to delete `super.onBackPressed();` also.By default , it is there in the function.

Comment: not working.this is my code.@Override public void onBackPressed() {

}

Answer (score 0):

You can declare global variable disableEvent by

```
final boolean disableEvent;
```

Your Preexecute method can set it to false by

```
disableEvent = false;
```

Your Postexecute method can set it to true by

```
disableEvent = true;
```

Now override onBackPressed as:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (disableEvent)
        {
            // do nothing
        }
        else
        {
            // do something
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
@Override
 public void onBackPressed() {
 return;
 }
```

Hope this helps you out !