# How to disable on the App intro Activity

Tags: android, onbackpressed

I have made slides using this library and its all working fine . I am calling my introduction slides right after Splash Activity.

And the Intro of my app starts easily using [this](https://github.com/rubengees/introduction) awesome library. but then I got the problem

**what I am doing**

```
public void displayIntro() {
    List<Slide> slides = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        slides.addAll(generateSlides());
    }

    IntroductionBuilder introductionBuilder = new IntroductionBuilder(this);


    new IntroductionBuilder(this).withSlides(slides)
            .withOnSlideListener(defaultOnSlideListener).withSkipEnabled("Skip")
            .withPageTransformer(new ZoomOutPageTransformer()).introduceMyself();

}
```

> this is how I am displaying slides after my splash screen time ends

**My Problem:**

If user click on any slide it goes back to my splash screen which is very bad, I want to disable the back button of the slides but do not know How to do this.

**So My Real Question is**

How Can I disable the back button(of Device not the one given on each slide), so that It can prevent going to splash screen. If I kill the splash screen , this will probably go to home screen of device .

Any possible solution ??

Comment: I do not think so you can handle this directly unless and until you find your own work around inside your activity such as on Resume etc

Comment: you should check this [Disable back button in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779954/disable-back-button-in-android)

Comment: there is no appIntro Activity I am using in slides way , let me edit the question

Comment: from where displayIntro() method is being invoked?

Comment: I am invoking it after the splash screen time runs out . You can say the sleep time

Answer (score 0):

Possible work-around is when you are navigating to slides from splash activity, call **finish()** before firing intent for slides. In that way, when user press back button while on slides, it'll be navigated back to Home Screen (Launcher app) not your splash screen i-e (logical flow).

Comment: I know this dude , but I wan to disable the back button

Answer (score 0):

Try this out,

When you exit from splash screen then use `finish()` after Intent of `AppIntro` activity. so when user press back in app intro than you app exit instead of go to splash screen.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(splashActivity.this, AppIntroActivity.class);
startActivity(myIntent);
finish();
```

Comment: I know this , but I do not wan tthis either

Comment: than what you want ?

Comment: This seems to be a genuine solution. Why do you need Splash activity after Into activity has started. Doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: no I do not want this , I think you guys need to use this , generate slides , and then you would see that when you click on slides they would come back , if you have finished the splash activity before going to slides , then you would navigated to home , in both case I do not want to go anywhere either on home or on Splash. 

I just simply want that the slides stop taking back press