# How to Handle Back Press in an activity Which is Launched From Notification?

Tags: android, push-notification

In my app,if i'm press back button or home up button it will closes my app.
 it's only when the activity is opened by the notification click ,so now i want to go to previous activity or home activity after a back press.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable back button in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779954/disable-back-button-in-android)

Comment: Accept the answer if it helps

Answer (score 1):

**Do this To Go Back**

```html
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   Intent setIntent = new Intent(this,YOUR_CLASS.class);
   startActivity(setIntent);
   finish();
}
```

Comment: i know this my question is after notification clicked i launch activity b,if user back press it exits .

Answer (score 0):

Define this in your activity

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
// Your Action over here.
}
```