# Disable android back button on gaming app

Tags: android, buildbox

When I try to add back button removal code, it gives [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ickgd.png).

I created a game with `buildbox`, it's a drag and drop, and exported it to the Android Studio.
I want to disable the android back button. 
Please, I need help on how to go about this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable back button in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779954/disable-back-button-in-android)

Answer (score 1):

Add to your Activity class **EMPTY** `onBackPressed` method:

### In Kotlin:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {

}
```

### In Java:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

override `onBackPressed()` method also **remove** `super.onBackPressed()`

like

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // super.onBackPressed();
    }
```