# Disabling back button in AndroidX Fragment

Tags: android, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm using Single-Activity pattern(Fragments for each UI) for App development together with Android's Jetpack navigation. Each fragment represent a UI. Is there any simple way to disable back press action(soft/hardware button)?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable back button in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779954/disable-back-button-in-android)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like

```
class MyFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        // This callback will only be called when MyFragment is at least Started.
        val callback = requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this) {
            // Handle the back button event
        }

        // The callback can be enabled or disabled here or in the lambda
    }
    ...
}
```

Or to be more verbose and to have more control over your code:

```
public class FormEntryFragment extends Fragment {
     @Override
     public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
         super.onAttach(context);
         OnBackPressedCallback callback = new OnBackPressedCallback(
             true // default to enabled
         ) {
             @Override
             public void handleOnBackPressed() {
                 // Handle the back button event
                 // Leave empty do disable back press.
             }
         };
         requireActivity().getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(
             this, // LifecycleOwner
             callback);
     }
 }
```

You can read more in the documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-custom-back) and [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/OnBackPressedDispatcher) - I took the examples from there

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, Paul. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For requirements wherein the back press has to be disabled and possibly re-enabled based on certain criteria, use the following. The callback is initialised with isEnabled false. So the back pressed still works.

```
private var backPressCallback: OnBackPressedCallback? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    backPressCallback = requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this) {}.apply {
        isEnabled = false   // Callback is disabled, so back press is enabled.
    }
}
```

Now, to disable/enable back press, do this anywhere in the fragment:

```
// To disable back press
backPressCallback?.isEnabled = true 

// To enable back press 
backPressCallback?.isEnabled = false
```