# Android logout and exit

Tags: android, android-activity, logout

This is my scenario: After visiting several activities, a user logs out from the app and is redirected to the login page. what i want is if user press back button while in login page. i want my application exit/closed, instead back to previous activity

Any ideas on the issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Just write this code in OnClick method of OnClickListener of your logout button.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Login.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

It works for me.
Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

...or you could check logged state when an activity starts: if user isn't logged, take him to login screen...

Comment: great idea, strangely haven't thought of that. even though, async tasks could keep running even while you're being logged out.

Answer (score 0):

[Override back button to act like home button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000102/android-override-back-button-to-act-like-home-button)

and then just call `this.finish();`

Answer (score 0):

override onBackPressed, in which call android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid())

Answer (score 0):

I have used onResume method on activities for validate if user is connected:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

    if (currentUser == null) {
        finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I implement this behavior in next way.
I create LogOut class:

```
class LogOut {
    void addOnLogoutListener(LogoutListener listener);
    void removeOnLogoutListener(LogoutListener listener);
    void logout();
}
```

This is a global class.
When user want to logout he should call logout() methods - this method notify every listener.
In your activity add listener that finishes activity. I always add such listener in BaseActivity class to remove code duplication.
Also in App class you can define listener that starts LoginActivity or clear important resources when Logout is happened.

Answer (score 0):

Write this on your Login Activity back press method

```
    Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(startMain);
```