# onBackPressed to hide Not destroy activity

Tags: android

i know how to cancel back keypress, so that the activity / main window stays visible:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    return;             
}
```

my aim is to hide the activity, however, without finishing it, how do you do that in the onBackPressed event?

i.e. I would like to get as far as onPause(), but not evoke the onBackPressed() default behaviour that essentially calls finish(). another way to put it is that i would like to mimic onUserLeaveHint() ?

any help appreciated!

Answer (score 64, accepted):

If you want to mimic the "Home" button on specific Activities just do this:

**Below API 5**:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

**Above and on API 5**:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  moveTaskToBack(true);
}
```

It will move the Task to background.. when you return, it will be as it was.

You can see more information about this here: [Override back button to act like home button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000102/android-override-back-button-to-act-like-home-button)

Comment: I ended up with this, fantastic working one-line solution!
`public void onBackPressed() {
 moveTaskToBack(true);
 return;
}`

Comment: That method is available on most recent APIs, you should of course also override it. :-)

Comment: Hii, this hide my whole application but i want just hide particular Activity not a whole application..

Comment: @Cel btw, you don't need the return on the onBackPressed :-)

Answer (score 18):

If you want to mimic the "Home" button on specific Activities :

**1st Method :**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   Log.d("CDA", "onBackPressed Called");
   Intent setIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
   setIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
   setIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
   startActivity(setIntent);
}
```

**2nd Method :**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   moveTaskToBack(true);
}
```

And if you want to move to the previous activity without destroying current :

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    startActivity(new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, DestinationActivity.class);
}
```

And now from any activity if you want to open the activity which is in Background . I name CurrentActivity. you could call it form anywhere..like..it wil take that actvity and put it to top of stack . and open it where you left off.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(FromAnyActivity.this, CurrentActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(intent);
```

*Flags :*

`FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` : To reorder the activity from stack

`FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` : To remove all the activities from the top

Answer (score 5):

If you don't destroy your activity you must set acitvity launch mode to single_instance and use moveTaskToBack(true) to send to background.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can't move back in the current stack without `finish`ing the activity. Perhaps you could detect `onBackPressed()` and then launch the home intent in a new task:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
        i.addCategory("android.intent.category.HOME");
        i.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
        i.addCategory("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(i);
    return;             
}
```

Let me know if that works.

Comment: i didnt try this one as the one-line solution from NeTe worked, but thanks nevertheless!

Comment: That is a nifty method: wasn't aware it was out there.