# Prevent activity from being destroyed

Tags: android, android-activity, android-camera-intent, android-ondestroy

I'm sending an intent to the camera from an activity that I call like this:

```
 Intent testphoto = new Intent(Dashboard.this,CameraHandler.class);
 startActivity(testphoto);
```

In the `CameraHandler` class I call the camera:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

But before `onActivityResult` gets called in the `CameraHandler` class the activity is destroyed. Is there anyway to prevent this?

FOUND THE ANSWER:
I had `noHistory="true"` in my `AndroidManifest` and that made the OS destroy the activity before the result.

Comment: how do you know its getting destroyed?

Comment: I´ve put a Log in the OnDestroy() method, I tried a single app with only one activity and it works fine, but when I start using this in a more complex app the activity gets destroyed before the camera returns the image

Comment: If you've found your own answer, post it and accept your own answer in order to close the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 43):

Be sure you don't have the "Don't keep activities" Developer setting on, as it will destroy the activity you are leaving.

Comment: QA reported an issue - I could only reproduce it on the phone they use.  I could not figure out why the activity ket exiting!  Didn't know about this setting till I saw your comment.  Thanks :)

Comment: it was only on my tablet.. the issue...thanks bud +1

Comment: +100. Why is this even an option? It has soo many side-effects!

Comment: Thank you very much. I have been struggling trying to find out why it is begin destroyed on my phone while in the emulator it is not.

Comment: Some issues are so much haunting....There should be a movie on Developer code envy....

Comment: This does not work as I don't have this option enabled either :(

Comment: Lol what's the point of this option, I was going crazy trying to figure this out

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to worry about the calling `Activity` being destroyed when you call `startActivityForResult()`, as it won't change the expected behavior at all (i.e. the child activity will remember to pass the result back to the parent whether the parent is destroyed or not). See this [**post**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10319330/844882).

Also note that while it is sometimes necessary to prevent `Activity`s from being destroyed (i.e. on configuration changes, etc.), in general you want to leave the `Activity` lifecycle alone and let the system manage background `Activity`s for you. Once you launch a new `Activity`, you shouldn't be explicitly preventing previous `Activity`s from being destroyed.

Comment: Only thing is that suddenly onActivityResult never is called, when I have an App with only one activity, the activity is never destroyed, but onActivityResult is called, now when inside another app suddenly the activity is destroyed and the result never seem to come back. Any idea how that can be?

Comment: Perhaps there is something wrong with your workflow. It seems odd that you are calling `startActivityForResult()` twice. You definitely need to call `startActivityForResult()` when launching the actual camera application, but I'm not so sure that you need it for the `CameraHandler` class. What is the `CameraHandler` class anyway? Is it possible to launch the camera app directly from the dashboard?

Comment: I need a screen in between, so directly from the dashboard is not an option, I found that startActivityForResult would prevent destroying the activity, but it does not, so indeed I might just as well remove that. The Camerahandler sends the intent to the camera and uploads a photo onactivity result, which it doesnt do now..

Comment: OK, so just to be clear... you have removed the `startActivityForResult()` call from your dashboard? (you might want to update your original post).

Comment: Have you taken a look at this? I can't tell you for sure what is wrong with your code based on the information you have given me, but I can tell you that something is definitely wrong if `onActivityResult` is never called when the `Activity` returns. Check out the sample code [**here**](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/index.html) and see if it helps.

Comment: thanks, hopefully I´ll find something. I posted the entire camerahandler class.

Comment: @AlexLockwood hello can you please tell me the right way to start activity startActivityForResult i m facing same issue just because of activity being killed

Comment: "it won't change the expected behavior"- sure it can. if you keep state in your activity and don't save that state.

Answer (score -3):

You have to mention in your manifest as

```
 android:persistent="true"
```

Below SO posts answers the same question

[How to make an activity stop, rather then be destroyed, from the BACK key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791493/how-to-make-an-activity-stop-rather-then-be-destroyed-from-the-back-key/35789879#35789879)

[How to prevent call of onDestroy() after onPause()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557255/how-to-prevent-call-of-ondestroy-after-onpause/35789825#35789825)

[Prevent activity from being destroyed as long as possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22168287/prevent-activity-from-being-destroyed-as-long-as-possible/35789751#35789751)

Comment: This attribute does not exist for activities: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Comment: @jekatt it does exists https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html

Comment: This is for the application, not the activity.