# Restoring previous state on android when switching between activities

Tags: android, user-interface, android-intent, android-activity

I have two activities and I can change from one activity to other by swiping (i am overriding `overridePendingTransition()` in base activity which two activities are being inherited) and I am using intents to switch between activities. But when I come from second activity to first, I don't want to create a new intent rather I use previous state. (I have lots of data on UI of both activities, I prefer not to redraw everything and sharing `Bundle` between activities). When I am going to second activity I did not destroy the first one. How can I restore that state, basically `UI` should not change?

Comment: use `finish();` in second activity instead of using Intent to call first activity.

Comment: What if I want to restore second activity?

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6791493/how-to-make-an-activity-stop-rather-then-be-destroyed-from-the-back-key)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can switch between 2 activities like this:

In activity A, when you want to switch to activity B do:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, B.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(intent);
```

In activity B, when you want to switch to activity A do:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(intent);
```