# Back button works like home

Tags: android

Is it possible to change this code:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

so that when I click on back button it works like a home button?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - How To Override the "Back" button so it doesn't Finish() my Activity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141996/android-how-to-override-the-back-button-so-it-doesnt-finish-my-activity)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this,

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent backtoHome = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        backtoHome.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        backtoHome.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(backtoHome);
    }
```

Adding this to your Activity, will make it look like your app is responding to a Home Button Click event

Answer (score 0):

**One line solution**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   moveTaskToBack(true);
}
```

And also [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23759328/1925394)

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
    //super.onBackPressed();
    NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
}
```

If something doesn't work like expected try it with uncommented

```
    super.onBackPressed();
```