# Back button -> emulate home button

Tags: java, android

I want hide my app, if press BACK button.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  
{
     if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0)
     {
        this.moveTaskToBack(true);
        return true;
     }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

But my app close. What i do wrong?

Comment: may be help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11240183/back-button-works-like-home?rq=1

Comment: You mean a crash? Why not call Finish?

Comment: i want emulate HOME button if i press BAck button.

Comment: @amisuno: run my answer and see if it works. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must override `onBackPressed()` method of Activity class. 
Here is a sample of code:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(startMain);
}
```

Also you must override `onBackPressed()` method in child activities:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    this.getParent().onBackPressed();   
}
```

Comment: NO! It's doesn't work for me.

Comment: may be it's doesn't work, because I use TabActivity?

Comment: You can override onBackPressed() in tab activity. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2796050/key-events-in-tabactivities

Comment: TabActivity is deprecated so it's a good idea to implement your application using Fragments

Answer (score 0):

By keeping activity at back do you mean the back button should act like a home button. If that is so try this,

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent backtoHome = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    backtoHome.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    backtoHome.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(backtoHome);
}
```

Adding this to your Activity, will make it look like your app is responding to a Home Button Click event, and your app will hide but not close.

Answer (score -1):

you can try this:

```
 Intent intent2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        intent2.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent2.putExtra("EXIT", true);
        startActivity(intent2);
```

**And into your MainActivity:**

Write this in onCreate()

```
if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("EXIT", false)) {
            finish();
        }
```

Try this. It will send you to the **HomeScreen**.

Comment: any comment by the downvoters??

Answer (score -3):

I'd recommend you reconsider. If every application were allowed to use the buttons however they wish, it would be impossible to maintain a certain consistency in user experience.

The physical buttons should work the same for all applications.A prof told me once: "Your app is nothing special." Not in the sense that it's not great, just that it should, optimally, follow certain standards so as to not confuse users.

Comment: How do you come to this conclusion?