# Send Application to background mode when back button is pressed in Phonegap

Tags: cordova

I have a problem with my phonegap application. I want to minimize the application (send App in background so that it's still running) when back button is pressed.

Here's my code.

```js
 document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
 function onBackKeyDown() {
 }
```

If I use `navigator.app.exitApp();` - my application will terminate
and If I use `navigator.app.backhistory()` - It will just go back to the previous page.

I want that if I press Back button, it will send me to Home screen and send the application to background so that it's still running. Thank you.

Comment: this one is better than using plugi guess http://stackoverflow.com/a/17700471/2769122

Answer (score 14):

you can use this [plugin](https://github.com/mohamed-salah/phonegap-backbutton-plugin)
then when device ready listen to backbutton and when onBackKeyDown use the plugin to launch the home screen

```
`document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
function onBackKeyDown() {
    navigator.Backbutton.goHome(function() {
        console.log('success')
    }, function() {
        console.log('fail')
    });
}
`
```

this plugin is just updated from [Dpa99c](https://stackoverflow.com/users/777265/dpa99c) answer for help user with cordova >=3

Comment: which version you use?

Comment: Great, it works with CLI 4.1, but is there any chance of making this plugin compatible with Windows Phone 8 as well? That'd be very much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot, using the referenced plugin and writing the override on `backbutton` event solved the issue

Comment: I can't believe you actually need to install a plugin to do this. Why is Cordova so crippled that it does not even provide the most essential functions? Do they have something against Cordova developers??

Answer (score 6):

Your best bet is to use a plugin to launch the home screen. I've already created one for my own purposes - you can download my Eclipse test project containing the source code and resulting compiled APK [from here](http://ge.tt/56OfHhm/v/0).

You would then use my plugin to override the default behaviour of the back button something like this:

```
function onBackKeyDown(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  cordova.require('cordova/plugin/home').goHome(function(){
    console.info("Successfully launched home intent");
  }, function(){
    console.error("Error launching home intent");
  });  
}
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
```

Here's the plugin source code:

**Home.java**

```
package org.apache.cordova.plugin;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

import org.apache.cordova.api.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin;

public class Home extends CordovaPlugin {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "HomePlugin";

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
        if ("goHome".equals(action)) {
            try {               
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                this.cordova.getActivity().startActivity(i);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Exception occurred: ".concat(e.getMessage()));
                return false;
            }
            callbackContext.success();
            return true;
        }
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Called invalid action: "+action);
        return false;  
    }
}
```

**home.js**

```
cordova.define("cordova/plugin/home", function(require, exports, module) {
    var exec = require('cordova/exec');
    var Home = function() {};
    Home.prototype.goHome = function(successCallback, errorCallback) {
        return cordova.exec(successCallback, errorCallback, 'Home', 'goHome', []);
    };
    var home = new Home();
    module.exports = home;
});
```

**config.xml**

```
<plugin name="Home" value="org.apache.cordova.plugin.Home"/>
```