# Android Cordova / PhoneGap 3.0 Back Button event

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am trying to bind a call to 'backbutton' event that is supposed to be called when a cordova app is run on an android device and the user hits the back button.

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#backbutton

I cannot seem to get this event to fire.

This google groups post references that the App plugin has been removed and doesn't seem to provide any solution, just wait for cordova 3.1.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/qgo-HdW4C_g

Answer (score 0):

According to the post in google groups the device api has not included in js file. So you need to wait for the next release.

This link may help you to use customize plugin to handle back button in android.

[Send Application to background mode when back button is pressed in Phonegap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17826122/send-application-to-background-mode-when-back-button-is-pressed-in-phonegap)