# Phonegap back button control

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm trying to get the back button to go to the home screen and keep the app open in the background but I can't seam to find out how to do it.

I have tried creating a plugin using Dpa99c's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17826122/send-application-to-background-mode-when-back-button-is-pressed-in-phonegap/) but I a. don't know where to put the java class before compiling and b. no matter where I try I just keep getting errors.

```
[phonegap] compiling Android...
   [error] An error occurred while building the android project.Error executing "ant debug -f ".../phone/news/platforms/android/build.xml"": 
BUILD FAILED
.../android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:720: The following error occurred while executing this line:
.../android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:734: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 6 seconds
```

Comment: Refer- http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.8.0/cordova_events_events.md.html#backbutton

Comment: Yea, I know about that and I know I can't do what I am trying to do in javascript. I am trying to put the app into the background and have it run in the notification area so the user can do other things whilst my app is still open and running.

Comment: I got the plugin installed by reading [this](http://devgirl.org/2013/09/17/how-to-write-a-phonegap-3-0-plugin-for-android/) tutorial and editing the files to fit with Dpa99c' code but it's still not working. I'll find out why but that's not for this question.