# Back without press "back" button

Tags: android

In AActivity, when button1 is press, then call BActivity.

```
Button b1= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(AActivity.this, BActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
}
});
```

In BActivity, I want that when button2 is press, then recall AActivity.

```
Button b2= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
//How to do?
}
});
```

I want back without press "back" button on keyboard.
And replace with button in layout.
How should I do?

When call back to AActivity, is it possible to run the onCreate() method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only you have to finish the activity by calling `finish()` method

**Sample code**

```
Button b2= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
finish();
}
});
```

Comment: I don't think it's good way to deal with onBackPress. It just suitable for Activity Stack,not all,like Fragment!In this case you should use

Comment: `FragmentManager ft = getSupportFragmentManager();`
                    `ft.popBackStackImmediate();`

Answer (score 3):

maybe just call `finish()` in your activity.

Answer (score 3):

You'll get the "Back" button functionality by this simple code :) As the back button on the phone is just finishing the current activity causing previous activity on the activity stack to start again.

```
Button b2= (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
finish();
}
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In the onClick() method of button2, you could just put

```
finish();
```

or you could specify a new Intent with AActivity.class as the target.

Answer (score 1):

```
Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(BActivity.this, AActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should override onKeyDown() method to enable the back button functionality. [Override back button to act like home button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000102/android-override-back-button-to-act-like-home-button) link will help you to achieve this.