# How to capture an event when a user dismiss an alert dialog by pressing the backKey in Android

Tags: android

I need to catch an event when the user presses the back key and try to dismiss the dialog
I have a code like this

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(AppNotification.this).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Caution");
    alertDialog.setMessage("Alert");
    alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        finish();
    } });
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Now here i have given the user an option,But suppose if he presses the back key then i need to perform some other action.how to do it?

Comment: [Here][1] is a similar question with an accepted answer.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000102/android-override-back-button-to-act-like-home-button

Comment: Nope.. I am talking about alert dialog and back key event... i know about the BackKeyEvent....

Comment: It was a hint how to override the back button. Rajeel explains how to add it to alert.

Comment: Yup Rajeel way will accomplish what i need to do.. Still i was looking for some better performance ways :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This will help you

```
alertDialog.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
        // Your code ...                
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There is also

```
alertDialog.setOnDismissListener(dialog -> { /* code goes here */ });
```

which seems to be handling specifically the dismiss event.

Answer (score 1):

You can capture the back key event
when your alert appears set some boolean to true

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(AppNotification.this).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Caution");
    alertDialog.setMessage("Alert");
    alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        finish();
    } });
  isAlertShowing = true;   // set to true for alert
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

then in event

```
@Override
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
 {
  if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) 
        {
            if(isAlertShowing)
            {
               // perform your task here
             }

        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
 }
```

Comment: This is a nice way... I was thinking of any listeners which the alert dialog has... :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a button for managing the back key event. Now inside the onClick event try to provide the below given code.

```
back_key.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{

        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
             // Your Tracking Code
        }
});
```