# Confirm application closure when pressing back button

Tags: android, application-close

How can I make it so that pressing the back button does not close my application? I want to display a confirmation message.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you saying you want to display a confirmation message as in something like "Press back again to exit"? And you want the second press of the back button to do something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Source: [Override back button to act like home button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000102/android-override-back-button-to-act-like-home-button)

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        //Display confirmation here, finish() activity.
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

That was a very quick search, try to look a little next time.

Answer (score 3):

Application close confirmation is here

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage("Do you want to close?")
               .setCancelable(false)
               .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        //do finish
                    ImageViewActivity.this.finish();
                   }
               })
               .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       //do nothing
                       return;
                   }
               });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();


    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this on back button pressed it shows confirmation message

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Thank You!!!!!")
           .setCancelable(false)
           .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                   //do things
               }
           });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to exit your Android Application.Android's design does not favor exiting an application by choice, but rather manages it by the OS. You can bring up the Home application by its corresponding Intent:

You can fire this Intent on  `onKeyDown()` in Android 1.x  and higher or `onBackPressed()` in Android 2.x and higher

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

A simpler approach is to capture the Back button press and call moveTaskToBack(true) as follows:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```