# How do you control what the BACK button does?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an application that when a button is clicked it changes the content view, but when I press the back button, it closes the activity. How do I change what the back button does. In this case it will be the back button changing the layout again.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must override `onBackPressed()` in your activity.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //your code when back button pressed
}
```

The `onBackPressed` method is called when the back Button is pressed, for that, you must change the content of this method by overriding it.

Answer (score 3):

Solved here: [Override back button to act like home button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000102/android-override-back-button-to-act-like-home-button)

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        //Do what you want here
        moveTaskToBack(true);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can override onBackpressed:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // Do your stuff....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The new recommended way is to use OnBackPressedCallback API, which is more flexible than old `onBackPressed()` method and may be used not only from Activity or Fragment

See more details in [the official guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-custom-back) and [API reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/OnBackPressedCallback)