# Android onKeyDown() not execute on pressing back button

Tags: android, android-keypad

Hi after searching on google i come here to ask about help. I use following method to go back when user press back button of device.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {


        Log.i("===BACK BUTTON PRESSED===", "BACK BUTTON");

        return true;
    } else {
        Log.i("===ELSE BACK BUTTON PRESSED===", "ELSE BACK BUTTON");

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

But logcat does not display any log message.

```
W/KeyCharacterMap(517): No keyboard for id 0
```

`W/KeyCharacterMap(517): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin`

Please help me to find this.

**EDITED QUESTION :**

This is my entire class.

```
public class Dreams_Reminder_detail_screen extends Activity {   

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
        GroupDreams.group.back();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.dreams_reminder_details_screen);        
}
```

}

Comment: override onBackPressed() method.

Comment: Does not work yet please help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can override [onBackPressed()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29) function and implement your logic there.

Please refer this android blogpost ["Back and other hard keys: three stories"](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/12/back-and-other-hard-keys-three-stories.html) for more understandings.

You can overrided onKeyDown function in GroupDreams perhaps that will work

Comment: i just put log in keydown function and it get printed, what's your issue now ?? i don't know about "GroupDreams.group.back();" because this will be your custom function.

Comment: I work with custometab activity. GroupDreams is my ActivityGroup. so if user press back buuton i go back to activity of GroupDreams. But does not work.

Comment: your activity is getting closed , if this is your issue then just remove moveTaskToBack(true);

Comment: I remove moveTaskToBack(true); but does not go back. i am so so stuck about this.

Comment: please refer this blogpost this show multiple activity under single tab with back button functionality http://ericharlow.blogspot.in/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14936/discussion-between-android-coader-and-hardik-joshi)

Answer (score 3):

Try this link: [Override back button to act like home button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000102/android-override-back-button-to-act-like-home-button)

```
    @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can trace the Back Button Event this Way :-

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();

     //Do the Logics Here 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with following code it will help you

```
@Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) 
        {
             }
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
        // do something on back.
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
//How to intercept the BACK key in an Activity is also one of the common questions we see //developers ask, so as of 2.0 we have a new little API to make this more simple and easier //to discover and get right:

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
// do something on back.
return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you wrote super method in else{} that was wrong.
Edit your code like this

```
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {


            Log.i("===BACK BUTTON PRESSED===", "BACK BUTTON");

            return true;
        } else {
            Log.i("===ELSE BACK BUTTON PRESSED===", "ELSE BACK BUTTON");


        }
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

}
```