# is this possible to run only a specified app in android device?

Tags: android

Our tablets need to run only a single application when the device starts. But should allow the user to change connectivity settings alone. Is this possible? if so how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Yes and please see the link in comment and also this to implement it

[Develop app run in kiosk mode in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14233304/develop-app-run-in-kiosk-mode-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

If the tablet is running Android 4.3 or newer, you can set up a [restricted profile](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/3175031?hl=en) to prevent launching any other apps.