# Prevent users from closing or minimizing an android app

Tags: java, android

I have an android app where the client will be let two tablets for experiments.

The question is: Is possible to prevent users from minimizing or closing the app? How can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Kiosk mode is what you are looking for! It was introduced in Android 4.2.

To enable kiosk mode, set this in your `activity_main.xml`:

```
<intent-filter>
<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" /> 
</intent-filter>
```

This question is most likely a dupe of: [Develop app run in kiosk mode in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14233304/develop-app-run-in-kiosk-mode-in-android)

Comment: Very thanks, was exactly that I need!! But I have only two questions: First: When I power on the tablet, the app in kiosk mode will automatically activate or I will need to open it first? Second: How can I power off the tablet? Because I will need block the power off button too. Thank you very much!

Comment: To start the application on boot, look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10428510/how-to-start-launch-application-at-boot-time-android


About the power button, I think the only way of disabling that is to physically remove it or block access to it. Most Android devices, especially those with non-removable batteries (most tablets), has a press-and-hold feature that forces the device to reboot. That "feature" is not possible to block in any way I know of.

Comment: When I try to put that it activity_main.xml, it tells me that it is not allowed there.  Has anything changed in Android 5?  Does this go somewhere else now?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested a way...
It is done on a fragment, you can test it yourself to do it from an activity

```
public void onDestroyView() {
    if(condition) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    super.onDestroyView();
}
```

This is done from an activity B with a fragment on it, then from the main activity, it returns to activity B. With this, the user can't close the app