# Button return = action button home

Tags: java, android, android-homebutton

I'm doing an Android app and I would know if this was possible:
When the user press the return button, it does the same action as the home button.

Comment: the return button in the softkeyboard?

Comment: the back button then?

Comment: I dont think you should override those 3 buttons with out a good reason. Are you trying to close your app down?

Comment: And do you know how to do this ? I found nothing

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000102/android-override-back-button-to-act-like-home-button

Comment: @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
        Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "back button pressed");
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
It's the good way ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32811/discussion-between-user1965878-and-doomsknight)

Answer (score 2):

Following the question I linked: [Override back button to act like home button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000102/android-override-back-button-to-act-like-home-button):

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Should be the solution.

This overrides the backbutton, and puts the task to the back. Which emulates hiding like the home button. Read the other question for more details, and solutions.