# Android exit from previous activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-navigation

I have 3 activities in my application

1. ActA
2. ActB
3. ActC

Suppose I am in activity `ActB` and I am loading `ActC` with out `finish();` `ActB`

Then when press a button in `ActC` , need to redirect the application to `ActB` . But this time when I press back from redirected `ActB` , another `ActB` ( previously loaded ) is showing.

Is there any way to kill all the activities which are previously loaded when we press the button in `ActC` ?

I am new to android and its ruining my time

Please help
thanks in advance

Comment: Do you need a new instance of `ActB` created when you click a `Button` from `ActC`? If not you can simply call `finish()` in `C` when you click the `Button`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you move like this
A -> B -> C
All the previous instances will be there in backstack for previous activities.
until and unless it is your requirement to create new instance of activity then only do so.
when you press button in you want to come to B but if you don't need new instance of B you can go with backstack item and according to me you should.

in button click you can simply call onBackPressed() of activity which is called when you press back button of device.

Also as Vee said you can use that flag to clear activities above your current activity.

Comment: hi I am moving like this A -> B . A is finished. Then I called like B -> C . B is not finished. When I came back like c -> B , then need to finish previously un-finished B and start a new B

Comment: @ramesh thats what i said ramesh if you want to finish actB while coming back from ActC to ActB why don't you just finish it while moving from B to C. if you press button in ActC to go to ActB and You want new Instance of B then use David's answer to do that. But is it really needed to make new instance every time? It is not recommended at all unless there is such kind of requirement.

Answer (score 2):

When you launch `ActC` from `ActB`, do so with this flag on the intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent (this, ActB.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

Javadoc:

"If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a new Intent."

Answer (score 2):

Just going from ActB to ActC, use Intent and finish() after calling the Intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActC.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

And then if you want to go back to B from C, then do the same in reverse, so switch

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActB.class);
```

And the rest is the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "kill" the activity you should call finish();

To achieve your goal you can do the following thing.

When starting ActB from ActA, after calling startActivity(...); put finish();

This way you killed Activity A, do the same in ActB when calling ActC. Then when you call ActB from ActC again, it will start a completely new activity.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But I need to goto ActB when press hardware back button from ActC .. By your suggestion, application will exit when press back .. any idea ?

Comment: Sorry i misunderstood you question then. You can override Key Press Back Button and start the activity you wish, here are some examples how it can easily be done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141996/android-how-to-override-the-back-button-so-it-doesnt-finish-my-activity  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000102/android-override-back-button-to-act-like-home-button   .

Answer (score 0):

If you don't *need* a new instance of `B` then you can simply call `finish()` in your `onClick()` of `C` and this will take you back to `B` and no need for `Intent` or any other code.

If you need a new instance of `B` then you can use Vee's suggestion, keeping in mind that this will clear `Activities` off of the stack if you add more in between.

If you don't need a new instance of `B` but want to pass data back to it then you can use the flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT`

```
Intent i = new Intent(ActC.this, ActB.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
// can send data to ActB if needed with putExtras()
startActivity(i);
finish();  // if you want to destroy C and take it off the stack
```

this will not create a new instance of `B` but bring it to the top of the stack so when you press the "Back" button, you will not have the second instance on there.

Answer (score 0):

When user presses button in `ActC` to goes back to `ActB` (by creating a new `ActB`) do this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActB.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

This will finish both `ActC` and the previous `ActB` and create a new `ActB`.