# Go to fist activity when open many activity

Tags: android

In my app I have two fragment in ManiActivity.class .
In my fragment I have a listview , when I click a item in list I open MainActivity2.class . In MainActivity2.class I have listview related and when i click list related I open MainActivity2.class with new value. Now I want create a button back home in MainActivity2.class and when I open many MainAcitivty2.class when click list related on it I can click button back home to go to MainActivity2.class
I try it with

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity2.this,MainActivity.class)
startIntent(intent)
```

But when I click back button in MainActivity.class it comback MainActivity2.class , it not exit app.
How I do to clear it? 
Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Override back button to act like home button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000102/override-back-button-to-act-like-home-button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is why Android maintains states of each activity in a Stack, that's why when you will press that Back-button, you just have to clear all previous activities from the stack and then open `MainActivity`

Just you have to set flags before starting intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity2.this,MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:launchMode="singleTask"` for your MainActivity in **AndroidManifest.xml**.

Which will keep only one instance of MainActivity if launched again this activity will come to top of the stack.
And Use this code

```
Intent intent = new Intent( MainActvity2.this, MyActivity.class );
intent.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP );
current_activity.startActivity( intent );
```

Answer (score 0):

call finish method after startIntent

something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity2.this,MainActivity.class);
startIntent(intent);
finish();
```

and put finish method in your activity

```
@Override
public void finish() {
    super.finish();
}
```

Comment: if my solution is working than You can show your thanks by accepting the answer

Answer (score 0):

its very simple.. use finish();

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity2.this,MainActivity.class);
startIntent(intent);
finish();
```

bcz u create multi activity in mainActivity2. so u have to destroy your activity before u go to mainActivty.

otherwise when u open new many in mainactivity2. that time use finish.. bcz u must have to destroy first your mainActivity2.

if you not understand my answer then just post your whole code... i will edit...