# Re-entering app and it's starting from the beginning?

Tags: android, android-intent

In my MainActivity class, I have a method that starts a new activity and kills the current one:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

In the new activity, if I press the back button, the app minimizes/closes as expected, but when I re-open the app, instead of showing up in NewActivity, it's gone back to MainActivity!

Why is this so?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/2000319/3790150

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because when it starts afresh, that is, even after you've ended the task, it launches the "Main/Launcher" `Activity`. You specify this inside the `AndroidManifest`.

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
    ...>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Pressing the back button, by default, finishes the current `Activity` and if no other `Activity` exist in the current task, the task is known to have ended.

The solution to this is to save some flag or state inside `SharedPreferences` or persist it somehow to read it again to direct the flow to `NewActivity`.

In your `MainActivity`, do something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(shouldStartNewActivity()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    } else {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}

private boolean shouldStartNewActivity() {
    //Your logic to check if NewActivity should be started directly
}
```