# Locking app to the screen

Tags: android, locking

I am trying to find a solution where in I buy an Android tablet, install my app, and lock the app to the screen. I mean the user can only use the app and cannot access the home screen (launcher, etc.). In this mode, the navigation bar, and volume buttons would be disabled.

I see that there is an option called Immersive screen mode in Android 4.4+ but it would reveal the navigation bar on inward swipe and there is a possibility of the user tapping on the home button.

The reason I am looking for such a solution is the intended users are not technically that great. They want to just use the app and not worry about going to home screen, clicking on app icon, switching wireless networks, etc.

For maintenance purposes, I am thinking of using a secret gesture that brings the user out of the app to home screen.

Is this possible? Can someone help me with suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same answer as was used her: [Override back button to act like home button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000102/override-back-button-to-act-like-home-button)

This will also work for the volume and home keys.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but wouldn't the stopped state prevent the working of the app? Sorry for posting a lame query.

Comment: I discovered the Screen Pinning feature in Android device but the client has Amazon Fire HD 6 and the Screen Pinning option is not available in it. Anybody know of any app that does this Screen Pinning?

I tried Child Profile, but again, the navigation bar is visible and there is an option to go back to home screen - so this solution isn't valid either.